# Sampling methods and parallelization

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

A couple of years ago I learned about recent work in [parallelizing slice sampling methods](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7477). More recently, I have read great things about [NUTS](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246) and [Hamiltonian Monte Carlo methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Monte_Carlo) (HMC) in general (e.g. [pymc3](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/tree/pymc3) uses NUTS) This makes me wonder:

- What are NUTS and HMC  **particularly good** for? Can they benefit from parallelization as much as, e.g. slice sampling?
- How do they compare to elliptical slice sampling and other methods in general?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but HMC and NUTS are often used in multilevel models, where you encounter high correlation among parameters at the (many) levels of model hierarchy.